# How to create a java class with static method called cage, that place X in a prison bar shape?

Tags: java, shapes

This is for my homework: How to create a public method called cage(char[][] arr) that returns a char[][]. The method should place Xs along the borders of the grid represented by the 2D array. In addition, it should place "bars" along the columns of the array, skipping one column for every bar. For example, if arr has 8 columns, the returning array looks like this:

```
 X X X X X X X
 X   X   X   X
 X   X   X   X
 X X X X X X X
```

my other shape was this: Create a java class ArrayArt with static methods as specified below:
a public method called frame(char[][] arr) that returns a char[][]. The method should put Xs along the borders of the grid represented by the 2D array and then it should return that array. For example, if arr has 4 columns and 4 rows, the resulting array should be:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java ArrayArt

  X X X X
  X     X
  X     X
  X X X X

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

The source code for the frame printing is next:

```
 public class  ArrayArt{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        printArray(frame(4,4));

}

// frame printing
public static char[][] frame(int n, int m ){
    char[][] x=new char[n][m];

    for(int row=0;row<x.length;row++)
        for(int col=0;col<x[row].length;col++)
            if( row == 0 || row == n-1 || row == col+row || row == (row+col)-(m-1) )
                x[row][col]= 'X';
            else
                x[row][col]= ' ';

    return x;       
}

//printArray        
public static void printArray(char[][] arr){
    for(int row=0;row<arr.length;row++){
            for (int col=0;col<arr[row].length;col++)
                System.out.print(" "+arr[row][col]);
            System.out.println();

}
}

}
```

Comment: @Bart thank you for the information, i wasn't aware of that (besides the fact that this is written in caps in the description-.-). Is there any substitue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this code after your else condition:

```
for(int i=1;i<x[row].length;i++)if(col == i*2)x[row][col]= 'X';
```

That shood do it! Good luck!